# Copy files from variable source and target locations and rename duplicates

Tags: batch-file, duplicates

Long time reader, first time poster - appreciate any help you can give.

**Context**: I am looking to tidy up a set of property folders.  Currently the parent folders are the projects and the properties are sub-folders.  If a property is affected by multiple projects it will be duplicated across the project folders.  My goal is to flatten the structure so I simply have one folder per property. (eg., copy from E:\TESTING\Project\Property*.* to E:\TESTING\Property*.*)  (NOTE: I'm looking to use a Windows batch script as I don't have permissions to load any custom software)

**Issue**: I need to consolidate files from the duplicate folders into a new location and ensure any duplicate files are kept and renamed with a suffix.  There are thousands of folders so I will need a looping script to minimize manual effort.

**Attempt**: I found a great script in the forums (copied below) that handles the duplicate file renaming really well and sets the source from a *.txt file.  I can't figure out how to set the variables so I can have custom/looping target folders.  (I'm happy to develop a *.txt file that will show the relevant target folder per source file if I need to)

Hoping it's something simple that I just don't know yet.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "source=E:\TESTING\source.txt"
set "target=E:\TESTING\Destination3\"


for /f "delims=" %%A in (%source%) do (
    if not exist "%target%\%%~nxA" (
        copy "%%~A" "%target%\%%~nxA"
    ) else (
        call :index "%%~A" "%target%\%%~nxA" "1"
    )
)
exit /b

:index  source, target, count
setlocal
set /a "cnt=%~3"

if exist "%target%\%~n2(%cnt%)%~x2" (
    call :index "%~1" "%~2" "%cnt%+1"
) else copy "%~1" "%target%\%~n2(%cnt%)%~x2"
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /ad "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO (
 rem project in %%a
 FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN (
  'dir /b /ad "%sourcedir%\%%a\*" '
  ) DO (
  rem property in %%b
  ECHO Project\Property being processed : %%a\%%b
  rem create new? property directory
  MD "%destdir%\%%b" 2>NUL
  rem for all files in the property directory,
  FOR /f "delims=" %%p IN (
   'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\%%a\%%b\*" '
   ) DO (
   IF EXIST "%destdir%\%%b\%%p" (
    rem existing filename - need to change
    SET "notcopied=Y"
    FOR /L %%r IN (1,1,99) DO IF DEFINED notcopied IF NOT EXIST "%destdir%\%%b\%%~np(%%r)%%~xp" COPY "%sourcedir%\%%a\%%b\%%p" "%destdir%\%%b\%%~np(%%r)%%~xp" >nul&SET "notcopied="
   ) ELSE (
    COPY "%sourcedir%\%%a\%%b\%%p" "%destdir%\%%b\%%p" >nul
   )
  )
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Not really sure why you're reading a file to provide your source directory - or is it directories?

Neither am I sure why you appear to be creating the copies in the same parent - Is there some way of distinguishing a property from a project?

Anyhow, the above routine simply assigns each project directoryname in turn to `%%a`, and then each project subdirectory to `%%b`. Then read each filename within `%%a\%%b` to `%%p`, create the required subdirectory in the destination (`2>nul` disposes of the `duplicate name` messages) and see whether the file already exists in the destination.

If it doesn't, copy it as-is. If it does, then try adding `(1)`... to the name part until the result is not found. The `notcopied` flag is used as a switch as `if defined` is interpreted with the current value of the variable, so setting `notcopied` to *empty* makes it not defined, so the loop doesn't try to execute the test further.

OK - the limitation is the final value for `%%c` - the duplicate-filename counter. I set 99 as the maximum. Adjust as required. The smaller the value you use here, the faster (or more accurately, less slow) the routine is.

Comment: > this is an elegant solution.  I've tested and it works perfectly, exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you so much :)